# I have some weird sizing and spacing issues going on between browsers

Tags: html, css

This is bugging me because it seems like it should be so simple. I'm going to attach the images of Chrome, FF, and IE 11.

First off, It's just a simple login with email and password inputs on the page centered vertically and horizontally.

HTML/JAVASCRIPT Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PHP Builds Login</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("Please fill out the username");
            return false;
        }
}   

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="loginform tmr">
    <form name="login" action="index_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <label for="usermail">Email: </label><br />
            <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required><br />
        <label for="password">Password: </label><br />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required> <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code (within `<head>`):

```
<style type="text/css">

html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    background: url('images/blue_sky.jpg');  
    font-size: 12pt;
}
body {
    display:table;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
section  {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}


label {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.tmr:before,
.tmr:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.tmr:after {
    clear: both;
}

.tmr {
    *zoom: 1;
}
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.loginform input:not([type=submit]) {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0,3);
    border-radius: 3px
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0pxrgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
                0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.loginform input[type=submit] {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background: #64c8ef; /*Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #64c8ef 0%, #00a2e2 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottombottom, color-
stop(0%, #64c8ef), color-stop(100%, #00a2e2)); /* Chrome, Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #64c8ef 0%, #00a2e2 100%); /* Chrome, Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #64c8ef 0%, #00a2e2 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #64c8ef 0%, #00a2e2 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottombottom, #64c8ef 0%, #00a2e2 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#64c8ef', endColorstr='#00a2e2', GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

</style>
```

On Chrome my password input is one space to the left making the inputs not aligned.

[image: Chrome]

Firefox they look perfect.

[image: Firefox]

Different sizes in IE 11.

[image: In IE 11 they are different sizes.]

Comment: Use only pt for print http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

Comment: You mean for text use pt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your question is : How to align elements properly (*because actually, there is no 'question' in your post*) :

Remove the space between input:password and `<br/>`

```
<label for="password">Password: </label><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    ...
```

Comment: yep, it was that space. doh! Thanks bud.

Comment: Where are my cookies ? Héhé, was a pleasure to help.